# Do we earn points for an answer that is part of Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

What if there are 10 up votes for an answer, before the question is changed to Community Wiki, and then after it is changed to CW, there is another 6 up votes.  Do we get 100 points for the 10 up votes or do we get 160 points for the 16 up votes total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the normal amount of "points" (reputation) until the answer or question turns into CW.

When this happens you won't be earning reputation anymore, but your old reputation won't be taken away either -- not even after a rep recalc.

Comment: To clarify, I believe this is only true now that question askers can't mark CW anymore. Before, when the asker converted the question to CW, all answers posted before then stayed non-CW, and still accrued reputation normally. Now the only way to make a question CW is by having a mod do it, and that will also convert all answers to CW at the same time