# Do answers to community wiki questions earn reputation?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Yesterday I asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105838/ankhsvn-glyphs-are-missing-from-business-intelligence-development-studio). Since initially asking the question, I have added images and neatened it up quite a bit. This has caused it to become a community wiki question.

I am concerned that people will be less likely to answer a community wiki question.

I have checked the following questions:

- [12 edits make an answer community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84424/12-edits-make-an-answer-community-wiki)
- [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)
- [Is there any point forcing a post to Community Wiki after 6 owner edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits)
- [SO is too eager to turn my edited answers into Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki)
- [I've accidently made an answer community wiki. How can I undo this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/ive-accidently-made-an-answer-community-wiki-how-can-i-undo-this)

But I haven't been able to determine what happens to answers that are posted to a community wiki question. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69281/do-we-earn-points-for-an-answer-that-is-part-of-community-wiki) leads me to believe that any answers to the question will not earn reputation for the answerer. Is this correct?

I have flagged the question and asked that it be changed back into a non community wiki, but I wonder if that was necessary.

Comment: _"I am concerned that people will be less likely to answer a community wiki question"_ -- last time I checked, this was exactly the purpose of CW, to repel contributors whose motivation is driven by rep. One needs to really want to share their knowledge "for free" to answer these

Comment: That's true, but not all that useful if your primary goal of asking a question is to get an answer. Lots of people, right or wrong, *are* motivated to answer questions by the magic internet points that they'll get. Some of them even know the right answer.

Comment: That makes sense for the "has more that n answers" community wiki reason but discouraging answers (and this really will discourage answers) on a question that has no answers just seems cruel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the answers to a CW question are also Community Wiki.

So by default, when answering, the answer will be CW and will not gain any reputation.

However, if the default changes (by moderator action - if you ask for it to be made not wiki and a moderator concurs) and the answer is no longer CW, then you will get reputation from votes on it, while it is not CW.

Comment: This only really applies to mods, though. Non-mods can't remove CW status nor can they make an answer to a CW question non-CW.

Comment: @waiwai933 - Things were not as I recalled. Thanks for the correction - answer updated.